# как достать из istream строку?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

```
IStream* pStream = NULL;
URLOpenBlockingStream(NULL,L"https://vk.com/aliexpressx24", &pStream,0,NULL);
string a;
```

Мне надо как то достать строку или строки из pStream,что бы найти в ней нужное значение,но я не знаю как извлечь строку и записать ее,например в обычный string.

Comment: Вызвать `Read`  несколько раз. Вроде элементарно же делается.

Comment: было бы неплохо если вы показали это на примере,потому что я чайник